# Work log in JIRA for daily meetings, retrospectives and specifications

Tags: project-management, jira

I hope that somebody with more experience (bad or good) can help me out here: I am setting up a project tracked in JIRA. The whole process with user stories, documentation, sprints, workflows, bamboo and fisheye integration, etc. is set up. But now I have a rather administrative question:

Where should developers log their work in meetings, such as stand-ups and retrospectives and for writing specifications (detailed descriptions of user stories to come)? I really cannot see what makes sense here, as I need the developers (obviously) to track this work, too. As far as I can see, the possibilities are:

1. Separate PROJECT-ADMIN JIRA project with simple, non-agile issues
2. Separate and parallel sprint with admin tasks
3. Administrative tasks for each sprint
4. Other versions??

Option 2 seems very hackish, as parallel sprints are just in a beta-stage for the JIRA agile (former Greenhopper) module. Option 3 seems a bit much work to setup for each sprint, and I am not sure, how this influences my velocity (ideally, I want to see the possible amount of story points that can be achieved in a sprint). Option 1 seems the most reasonable to me, but others have advised against it, unfortunately, without offering a solution. I haven't really looked into option 4, as IMHO this is very similar to option 2.

I couldn't see any best practices anywhere, so I would very much welcome any advice from more experienced people. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I face this exact issue with my team and this is what is working for us (for now) YMMV.

Our current structure is that we have a Roadmap type project (call this Planning) where all issues come into at first. Thereafter we create issues in related product projects (call this Product).

1. In the beginning of the lifecycle, any meetings, scoping, etc will have sub-tasks created and the time will be tracked on Planning. Once scoped and scheduled for work a new issue is created on Product and linked to this original issue.
2. Once the Product issue is assigned and the dev is called to any meetings whilst this issue is in a sprint we will create a sub-task on Product and assign the time. If the issue is not in a sprint we go ahead and create a new sub-task in Planning and assign the time there.
3. When then also have a project where we do Housekeeping type work. So if we need changes to JIRA, Stash, Confluence we will create the issues here. We will then create a new issue on Planning, link the issue and schedule that accordingly.
4. We have a meta project that acts as a bucket for anything that doesn't fall into the other categories which we sift through every now and again to identify if we need to create separate projects.
5. I have created a custom field that rolls up all the times of any linked issues found on the Planning board

Have a look at the Twitter blog [Visualizing Epics and Dependencies in JIRA](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/visualizing-epics-and-dependencies-in-jira) by Nicholas Muldoon maybe this can help you in some way too.

One caveat we are still exploring the best way to do this. Each environment is different and what works for us might not work for you.

Comment: Thank you, Deon. Although intriguing, I don't want to bother the (rather small) team with too many projects, and have therefore simply created one side project calld "<project> Administration", where we create and log work on all the tasks that are not in a sprint. That includes meetings, specifications, and some of what you call house-keeping. Although much of the latter is defined as task in our Sprint 0, I hope not too many new housekeeping tasks will arise. Regards, Marco

Comment: @marco awesome at a previous company we had a "meta" project to do this and it worked for us. If I was you I would keep a pulse on it and see if you ever need to expand out into additional projects / sub-task types.

Answer (score 4):

We use Tempo to log our billable work against JIRA issues, whether a single Epic for a small project or individual tasks for a larger project. For non-billable work we have a single project where people can optional log work, and we also use it for planning our time. So option 1 is the closest there. We could also have categories for different work logged in Tempo and handle this case that way.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. All our hours will be billed, but I see that option 1 may be an option. I have never used Tempo so far, as I'd like the devs to write their hours per check-in (with a smart commit) and I don't know whether that's possible in Tempo.

Comment: If you use smart commits then the work will appear in Tempo :)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue trying to track team member hours that are unrelated to the project or related to the project but not to a specific story or task.

Initially we went with **option 3** & had several administration tasks that persisted across sprints.  While this was relatively easy to implement it failed for us as we had team members that sat across multiple projects & as a result these administrative tasks that resided in each project were impossible to manage / report on for these team members.

In the end we went with what you have described as **option 1**. By creating a separate project with "non task related" issues such as Planning Meetings, Technical Issues & Client work then installing the *JIRA Misc Time Log & Report Extensions* plugin we could provide users with an easy means of logging times without having to change projects or boards (since the plugin adds a dropdown menu to the top navigation).

The plugin then allowed us to get reports on where team members we logging time off project regardless of how many projects they worked on concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and I know some time has passed since the moment this question was posted but maybe this is useful for a lot of people:

**Tempo has a dedicated feature for that thing you want to achieve and is called `Internal Issues`**.  not to be confused with `Internal activities`.

You can go there by navigating to `Config`>`System` and then click on the `add-ons` tab. Then scroll down to the Tempo section in the menu on the left bar and there you'll find a link that reads `Internal Issues`. There you can create the issues. Please keep in mind that before creating internal issues you have to create the tasks, for instance "Sprint Planning" or "Retrospective" in the project without assigning to anyone, just to the project.

When your users go to log their time for those "Internal Issues" they go to `Tempo` > `Timesheets` and then click in the upper right button that reads `log work`. There, in the right menu they'll see the "internal issue" option where they can pick those internal issues you previously created and log the time that the team spend on SCRUM Ceremonies.

Comment: This works pretty good for us too!